# ElasticSearch generic url only 10 item return

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a reason that a generic search on a index only returns 10 items?
If so how can I set the limit higher?

`http://localhost:9200/journal/_search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 is just the default number of search hits that will get returned. Take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

There you find a lot of parameters to append to your URI Search. You need to set the **size** parameter like so:

```
http://localhost:9200/journal/_search?size=100
```